# I'm using lombok for my project,but it does not work when compile

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

My ide is intellij idea 16.2 and lombok version is 1.16.10.
I have checked "Enable annotation processing" and also installed newest lombok plugin 0.12.16.So what can I do then?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem.I think it's my error of configuration of web app. This project is a web app, and I run it using tomcat runner,so I should set the docBase as the project root dir, but webapp or webcontent of the root dir

Comment: This seems to be a very particular solution, not answering the question in general.